# Why am I getting `ValueError: duplicate` when passing a list to `metafunc.parametrize` in `pytest_generate_tests`

Tags: python, pytest

I'm passing a json file in with the following:

```
#config.json
[
{
    "id" : 1,
    "description" : "test1",
    "data1": [1, 2, 3],
    "data2": ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    
},
{
    "id" : 2,
    "description" : "test2",
    "data1": [4, 5, 6],
    "data2": ["baz", "foo"]
}
]
```

Trying to use data1 to create test permutations. The most rudimentary way to cause the problem is:

```
#######################
# conftest.py
import json
import pathlib
import pytest

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    print("pytest_generate_tests")
    config = pathlib.Path(metafunc.module.__file__).with_name('config.json')
    testdata = json.loads(config.read_text())
    for test in testdata:
        metafunc.parametrize('testdata', testdata)
        metafunc.parametrize('data', test.get('data1'))

#######################

#test_example.py
import pytest

def test_example(testdata, data):
    pass
```

Which gives the error:

```
external_data/conftest.py:11: in pytest_generate_tests
    metafunc.parametrize('data', test.get('data1'))
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest-6.2.3-py3.9.egg/_pytest/python.py:1100: in parametrize
    newcallspec.setmulti2(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest-6.2.3-py3.9.egg/_pytest/python.py:932: in setmulti2
    self._checkargnotcontained(arg)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest-6.2.3-py3.9.egg/_pytest/python.py:909: in _checkargnotcontained
    raise ValueError(f"duplicate {arg!r}")
E   ValueError: duplicate 'data'
```

What I would like to see is both of the wider structures be tested for all the permutations of data1 (and eventually data2)

```
external_data/test_example.py::test_example[testdata0-1] PASSED
external_data/test_example.py::test_example[testdata0-2] PASSED
external_data/test_example.py::test_example[testdata0-3] PASSED
external_data/test_example.py::test_example[testdata1-4] PASSED
external_data/test_example.py::test_example[testdata1-5] PASSED
external_data/test_example.py::test_example[testdata1-6] PASSED
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the list to parametrize, otherwise you're just calling `parametrize('data',...)` multiple times with different args.

Something like this should work:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    print("pytest_generate_tests")
    config = pathlib.Path(metafunc.module.__file__).with_name('config.json')
    testdata = json.loads(config.read_text())
    data = [test.get('data') for test in testdata]
    metafunc.parametrize('data', data)
```

parametrize takes an iterable as a second argument.

Comment: data becomes a list of lists [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]. `test.get('data1')` returns an iterable list.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar but slightly different issue: in my case it was because the hooks was defined in the same file as the test.

```py
# my_pytest_module.py

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'test_params' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("test_params", ['1', '2', '3'])

def test_example(test_params):
    print(test_params)
    assert True
```

This was giving me the following error :

```py
    raise ValueError(f"duplicate {arg!r}")
E   ValueError: duplicate 'test_params'
```

Separating the test to a separate test file solved the issue

```py
# test_example.py

def test_example(test_params):
    print(test_params)
    assert True
```

In the question it is already in separated file, however I adding this as a potential answer for others that could find to this behavior